# installed geolocator but ImportError: cannot import name 'DummyLocator'

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, geopy, geolocator

I Have installed geolocator and when I use `pip install geolocator` it returns:

> Requirement already satisfied: geolocator in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.1.1)

but when I try to import it with `import geolocator` raises this error:

```
Fail to execute line 2: import geolocator
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/1657524228602-0/zeppelin_python.py", line 158, in <module>
exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geolocator/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from geolocator import DummyLocator, MaxMindCityLocator, MaxMindCountryLocator
ImportError: cannot import name 'DummyLocator'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by installing packages with this order:

```
pip install geopy
pip install Nominatim
```